# Locate images in html outside jar

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

In my application, i have to generate images on fly using java code and have to give a path of generated image in html page to show generated image to the user in html.

In my case,we can not place generated image in jar file on fly.So I can generate image file outside of the jar.But i can not locate image in html file.

Can you please help me out on this.

Jar file location is java -jar /usr/syam/test/test.jar

but i am generating images in /usr/syam/captcha/test.jpg

in html file,

Please help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried already? You might get more help if you add existing code etc.

Comment: Just a humble opinion: when you generate captchas I wouldn't store them on the filesystem and deliver them through the app server but would directly send them back in the outputstream using ImageIO.

Answer (score 9):

You can use resource handler e.g.

```
@Component
class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/captcha/**").addResourceLocations("file:///usr/syam/captcha");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sodik,Thanks for your answer. <img src="/captcha/photo.jpg" style="" border="1"> is not working.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more information such as: your WebInitializer/web.xml, and the actual spring mvc logs when loading the URL "/captcha/photo.jpg" (turn on DEBUG for "org.springframework.web.servlet.resource"

Comment: I assume that you have a `photo.jpg` in proper directory and that your application "starts' on ROOT context. If so, pls provide the information as Brain asked and maybe add what does it mean that it does not work - do you get 404?

Comment: thank you bro thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 i searched this about 15 hours